# Create event with Microsoft Teams online meeting using Microsoft Graph Java SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

Searching in the Microsoft Graph documentation, I found this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

It says that you can create an event with an online meeting using Java "Event" type.

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP6DS.png)

But the problem is, when I tried to do it with the current last [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/1.7.1) version 1.7.1, I noticed that "event.isOnlineMeeting" and "event.onlineMeetingProvider" don't exists.

Is it not implemented yet? Or I'm missing a new Microsoft Graph version, or something...

## Edit 1

I clarify, this is not a code error, rather it is about knowing why Microsoft Graph documentation shows an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example-4-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting) of Java code which makes use of "event.isOnlineMeeting" and "event.onlineMeetingProvider", while In the latest version of the Microsoft Graph SDK for Java, these fields of the "event" object do not exist.

- [Microsoft Graph API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0)
- [Microsoft Graph Git repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/models/extensions/Event.java)

## Edit 2

In the latest versions of the Microsoft Graph SDK for Java, the event object already has both fields.

Comment: We could not reproduce the issue on our side. Could you please share the screen shots of the issue what you are facing?

Comment: In the document you have provided we could able to see the "event.isOnlineMeeting" and "event.onlineMeetingProvider". Could you please see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8WJ0.png) and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#json-representation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest versions of the Microsoft Graph SDK for Java, the [Event](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/models/Event.java) object already has both fields.

[image: isOnlineMeeting]

[image: onlineMeetingProvider]

Comment: Please share code as formatted text, not as images.